# Rearrange docs in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I want to reposition the params docs, I had written the docs for my code earlier. Now I have rearranged the arguments of my method, I want the same to reflect in my docs written above my method. How can I do this, is there any shortcut keys? I don't want to do it manually. I have too many methods.

**Earlier code and docs**

```
/** Places the spinner on the screen on specified co-ordinates and customized drop down menu.It can be used for various option selection purpose.

 * @param options The list of items the that is to be shown in the spinner's drop down menu.
 * @param xCordinate The start point of the this view along x [To be given in cell number].
 * @param yCordinate The start point of the this view along y [To be given in cell number].
 * @param spinnerTextSize Text size of the text that is displayed on the spinner.
 * @param spinnerTextColorCode The color of the text on the spinner,stored in database.[HTML color codes or Hex codes].
 * @param spinnerWidth The width of the spinner.
 * @param fontSize Text size of the text that is displayed on the spinner's drop down menu.
 * @param fontColorCode The color of the text(stored in database) on the spinner's drop down menu.[HTML color codes or Hex codes].
 * @param dropDownBackgroundColorCode The background color of the spinner's drop down menu,stored in database.[HTML color codes or Hex codes].
 */
```

**public void** spinner( **int[]** options, **int** xCoordinate, **int** yCoordinate, **final float** spinnerTextSize, **int** spinnerTextColorCode, **int** spinnerWidth, **float** fontSize,  **int** fontColorCode, **int** dropDownBackgroundColorCode);

**Repositioned arguments in the above method**

**public void** spinner(**int** spinnerId, **int** xCordinate, **int** yCordinate, **int** spinnerWidth, **final int** spinnerTextSize, **float** fontSize, **int** spinnerTextColorCode, **int** fontColorCode, **int** dropDownBackgroundColorCode, **int[]** options)

Comment: Thank u, but it will be better if eclipse IDE can provide this in future releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Eclipse's refactoring feature. Here is how:

Right-click on the method you want to change. `Refactor -> Change Method Signature...` or simply use `Alt-Shift-C`. In the menu that pops up you can change you method any way you want. In your case you will want to move parameters around. Select a parameter and use the `Up` and `Down` buttons to rearrange the list of parameters. This will also rearrange the documentation as long as the parameter names match up.

I would also like to issue some advice. You might want to look into the telescoping anti-pattern and the use of the Builder pattern to get around this pitfall.

Comment: Awesome its working as you said @Eric Tobias..Thank u,Thank u,Thank u.